# React " this.props " returns undifined

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a course on CodewithMosh, in the course I initiate a function on click, this function then passes an ID to another component. This returns undefined. I tried passing a different value, and it worked perfectly fine. I don't understand what's the problem and or difference.

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state = { 
        counters: [
            {id: 1, value: 4},
            {id: 2, value: 1},
            {id: 3, value: 2},
            {id: 4, value: 3}
        ]
     };

    handleDelete = (counterId) => {
        console.log('Event Handler Called', counterId); //Function receiving data
    };


    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div className="main">
                { this.state.counters.map(counter => 
                <Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}>
                    <h4>Counter #{counter.id}</h4>
                </Counter>)}
            </div>
         );
    }
```

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        value: this.props.value
    }

    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += (this.state.value === 0) ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount(){
        const {value: count} = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }

    handleIncrement = () => {
        this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1});
    }

    render() { 
        return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
            <span style={this.styles} className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button onClick={this.handleIncrement } className={"btn btn-secondary btn-sm"}>Increment</button>
            <button 
                onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} //The ID I'm trying to pass.
                className={'btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2'}>
                    Delete
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: It does not appear that you are passing and `id` prop. Is that a typo in the question or the code?

Comment: I don't follow, I did as it was done in the tutorial, if I try to pass (this.props.value) it shows the value of the ones I click, I taught it would work just the same for ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the constructor render method inside the Counter component yet, and also pass the props to it. Do this;

```
class Counter extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: this.props.value
    };
}

getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += (this.state.value === 0) ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
}

formatCount(){
    const {value: count} = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
}

handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1});
}

render() { 
    return (
    <div>
        {this.props.children}
        <span style={this.styles} className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement } className={"btn btn-secondary btn-sm"}>Increment</button>
        <button 
            onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} //The ID I'm trying to pass.
            className={'btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2'}>
                Delete
        </button>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did as you showed me and it did not work. In the example in the course we don't use the constructor for this one or use the super. The odd thing is that if I pass (this.props.value) it passes the value, but when I try with Id i get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I didn't map the id.

Changed this

`<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value}>`

To this 
`<Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} value={counter.value} id={counter.id}>`